Amazon Bedrock CLI/API: how to associate an Action Group to an Agent Version
Can you please point me in the right direction to create/update a Bedrock Agent Version with an associated Action Group?
Right now I can do it from AWS Console UI only...
Also, I see a command to associate a Knowledge-Bases to an Agent Version:
// https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/bedrock-agent/associate-agent-knowledge-base.html 
  
associate-agent-knowledge-base \
     --agent-id <value> \
     --agent-version <value> \
     --description <value> \
     --knowledge-base-id <value>

But cannot find anything similar for Action Groups.
Thanks.
